# How to stop MediaBrowserServiceCompat?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediabrowserservice, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowser

My service:

```
public class MusicService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
...
}
```

My Activity:

```
public class MediaActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private MediaBrowserCompat mMediaBrowser;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMediaBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(this,
                new ComponentName(this, MusicService.class), mConnectionCallback, null);
        mMediaBrowser.connect();
}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaBrowser.disconnect();
    }
```

I want to add button close in UI, but how to stop `MusicService`? It continues casting in background.

Comment: You need to call stopForeground(true) if started with startForeground() followed by stopself() in MusicService

Answer (score 4):

I've declared a method in [`MediaSessionConnection`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/MediaSessionConnection.kt):

```
    class MediaSessionConnection(
        val context: Context,
        private val serviceComponent: ComponentName
    ) {
      ...
      fun release() {
        mediaBrowser.disconnect()
        mediaController.sendCommand("disconnect", null, null)
      }
      ...
    }
```

And in `MusicService`:

```
    class MusicService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

        override fun onCreate() {
            super.onCreate()
            ...
            mediaSessionConnector = MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession, object : DefaultPlaybackController() {
              override fun onCommand(player: Player?, command: String?, extras: Bundle?, cb: ResultReceiver?) {
                if (command == "disconnect") {
                  stopForeground(true)
                  stopSelf()
                }
              }

              override fun getCommands(): Array {
                return arrayOf("disconnect")
              }
            })
        }
    }
```

I do not claim,  that this is the correct way of stopping the service completely, but this is the solution that I've came up to after struggling some hours.

If `mediaBrowser.disconnect()` is not executed, then `stopSelf()` won't destroy the service (by telling *"destroy the service"* I anticipate `onDestroy()` to be called).

Without explicitly performing `stopForeground()` and `stopSelf()` simply performing `mediaBrowser.disconnect()` wouldn't destroy the service.

Comment: Is MediaSessionConnector only for exoplayer2? I don't use it I use MediaPlayer..

Answer (score 1):

To stop from anywhere:
getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), YourServiceName.class));